# Append to curl object and add to array in file with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, curl, jq

I'm trying to generate a json array of objects dynamically from a URL and save the array to a file. Is it possible to pipe curls output to jq modify the curl json object and then append it to a json list in a file and save the updated list back to the file?

The goal is to iterate over a list and hit a URL pulling the object down then adding a field to the object and writing the output to a single json file.

First we curl the url to get the user object and add a new field to it.

```
curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 | jq '. + {"level": 15}'
```

A diff showing what is being added to the object.

```
diff <(curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 | jq . ) <(curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 | jq '. + {"level": 15}')
```

Second we add that user object to the list in userList.json. This is the part that I'm stumped on.

Third we write that updated list back to the file.

```
JQ updated list command > userList.json
```

Curl URL for user object, append value to user object and append user object to array in file. I tried using `--argjson fileInfo "$(<userList.json)"` but couldn't seem to get it to work. I get an invalid path expression or other errors of not being able to add an object to an array. I've tried the `|= . +` but can't figure out how to reference the two data sets correctly.

```
echo -e "[\n]" > userList.json
for i in {1..4}; do
  echo -e "\n==> User ${i}"
  testUrl=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${i}
  curl -s ${testUrl} | jq --argjson fileData "$(<userList.json)" '. + {level: 15} += [$fileData]' > userList.json
done
echo -e "==> Complete"
jq . userList.json
```

A non-json way of creating the file but it's would be missing the comma separator between each user object, I could programmatically add the comma but I'd rather figure out jq and have it write proper json instead. Compare the output of this loop with the expected data below.

```
for i in {1..4}; do 
  testUrl=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${i}
  curl -s ${testUrl} | jq '. + {level: 15}' >> userList.json
done
```

Expected result of userList.json file, it's the 4 user objects with an added field level.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    },
    "level": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    },
    "level": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    },
    "level": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    },
    "level": 15
  }
]
```

Comment: @Inian I'm adding the "level": 15 to each users object. If you curl the URL alone you'll notice that "level" isn't a field for the user object by default. I'll include a diff of a single user before and after to give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know a better solution using jq with in the forloop to write the user data to the array with in the file let me know. I'm really interested in understanding if that is possible with jq.

I would prefer if I didn't have to write to a temp file and instead could read from the file append the new curl user data and write back to the file within the for loop but I get the results and proper json this way.

My semi decent solution using JQ. I end up writing multiple user files and then combine them together with slurping.

```
for i in {1..4}; do
  echo -e "==> Creating a temp user json file for user${i}."
  testUrl=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${i}
  curl -s ${testUrl} | jq '. + {level: 15}' >> /tmp/temp_user_${i}_information_file.json
done

echo -e "==> Creating the final users json file."
jq -s '.' /tmp/temp_user_*_information_file.json > userList.json
```